# pass a list within a list as an argument to subprocess in python

Tags: python, list, subprocess

I am trying to pass a `list` within a `list` as an argument to the `subprocess`. My code is:

```
def test():

    x= 'a'
    y = 'b'
    filename = "test.log"
    error_list = []
    error_list.append(x)
    error_list.append(y)
    para = ['1','2',str(error_list)]

    ret = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"script.py"]+para)
    ret.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

On the subprocess script side when I access this script like this:

```
def test(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    content = arg1 + arg2 + arg3
    print content
if __name__ == "__main__":

    arg1 = sys.argv[1]
    arg2 = sys.argv[2]
    arg3 = sys.argv[3]
    test(arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

The first two arguments come correct in `content` but the third argument comes as `[, ', a, ', ,,  , ', b, ', ]` while I want it to be just `a,b`

Comment: why are you calling str on the list? You realise your list becomes `"['a', 'b']"`? I don't see how you would get  `[, ', a, ', ,,  , ', b, ', ]` either with the code supplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints `12['a', 'b']` because `"['a', 'b']"` is the string representation of the list `[x,y]`.

If your expected output is `12a,b`, replace

```
para = ['1','2',str(error_list)]
```

with

```
para = ['1','2',','.join(error_list)]
```